# increase temporary cache

Tags: 14.04, cache, caching

I have a server at work that is running 119 cameras.  I am needing to increase the temporary cache for said server.  It is a HP DL380-G7 machine running Ubuntu 14.04.5

It has 72gb of RAM, 2x2.67ghz xeon processors, and eight 300gb hard drives set up in a RAID 5 with the 8th hard drive as a spare.

With 119 cameras that are recording motion, the cache is starting to fill up and then I don't get all of the videos recorded.

I'm running Ubiquiti's UniFi Video. The error message I'm getting is that the "Temporary Video Cache is full." It was suggested by a Ubiquiti employee that I increase the RAM cache to 25%

It was suggested on the camera manufacturer's support community that I increase the size of the temporary cache, and one user even said that he had done that on a system that he had and it solved his problem of videos not recording.  But I don't know how to increase the cache.  Can someone help me out?

Thank you!!

Comment: Which cache? How are the streams recorded? Which software?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I could/should post the manufacturer.  I'm running Ubiquiti's UniFi Video.  The error message I'm getting is that the "Temporary Video Cache is full."  It was suggested by a Ubiquiti employee that I increase the RAM cache to 25%.

Comment: There is probably some kind of configuration of cache size provided by the vendor's software. If that is the case, we've no way to know how it is done, and it's also unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: Apparently you're also discussing this at https://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Video/Temporary-Video-Cache-space-is-90/td-p/2313661, and have received some good advice there.